# How can I make my elements hover independently of one another?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why do these blocks depend on each other on hover? How can I make them hover independently? As of now, the first list__item depends on the second list__item.

```css
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.list__item {
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    list-style: none outside;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 23.72%;
    margin: 0 0 20px 1.7%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.list__item:hover .list__descr {
    display: block;
}
.list__name {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.286;
    padding: 20px 8px;
    height: 73px;
}
.list__descr {
    display: none;
    padding: 0 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #505050;
}
.list__descr-more {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #787878;
    line-height: 1.909;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__img">
        </div>
        <div class="list__title">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
        </div>
        <p class="list__descr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, pariatur! Quasi sed eaque praesentium ea odio voluptatibus repudiandae commodi, ut cupiditate perferendis voluptate provident, nobis ullam doloribus accusantium omnis perspiciatis.</p>
        <div class="list__descr-more">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__img">
        </div>
        <div class="list__title">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
        </div>
        <p class="list__descr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, pariatur! Quasi sed eaque praesentium ea odio voluptatibus repudiandae commodi, ut cupiditate perferendis voluptate provident, nobis ullam doloribus accusantium omnis perspiciatis.</p>
        <div class="list__descr-more">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: tried my best to make sense of the question, feel free to edit

Comment: @davethecoder If you're not sure what something would translate to, it's best not to translate it. Ask the OP to clarify or revise the question themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the `align-items: stretch`, which is by *default* and makes *flex-items* `stretch` to *fill* the *flex-container* along the *cross axis*, where their *height* is dictated by the *height* of the *"tallest"* one.

So in order to prevent that just change the *value* to `flex-start`, which will then preserve their *height* as it is:

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start; /* modified */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list__item {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  list-style: none outside;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 23.72%;
  margin: 0 0 20px 1.7%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.list__item:hover .list__descr {
  display: block;
}

.list__name {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.286;
  padding: 20px 8px;
  height: 73px;
}

.list__descr {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #505050;
}

.list__descr-more {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #787878;
  line-height: 1.909;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
    <div class="list__img"></div>
    <div class="list__title">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
    </div>
    <p class="list__descr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, pariatur! Quasi sed eaque praesentium ea odio voluptatibus repudiandae commodi, ut cupiditate perferendis voluptate provident, nobis ullam doloribus accusantium omnis perspiciatis.</p>
    <div class="list__descr-more">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <div class="list__img"></div>
    <div class="list__title">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
    </div>
    <p class="list__descr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, pariatur! Quasi sed eaque praesentium ea odio voluptatibus repudiandae commodi, ut cupiditate perferendis voluptate provident, nobis ullam doloribus accusantium omnis perspiciatis.</p>
    <div class="list__descr-more">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```